# SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 - How can I get the report to scale to one page wide when printing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report and it seems so insist on printing in portrait mode and splitting the report across two pages.

How can I make the web version specify landscape automatically, and also have it scale to fit on one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the PageWidth and PageHeight (which infer PaperSize)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677573.aspx) and older [SSW](http://www.ssw.com.au/Ssw/Standards/Rules/RulesToBetterSQLReportingServices.aspx#PageLayout)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can scale it to fit, but you can specify page orientation in the report properties when you are designing it (I think).

Apologies if that is incorrect, it's been a while since I did any SSRS.

This might help: http://www.blrussell.com/index.php/2007/08/13/ssrs-display-report-in-landscape/